# OrientDB query for vertices with no particular edge from another vertex

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases

I have a `Post` and a `User` vertices, related by a `Posted` edge.

I want to retrieve posts that have no posted relation from a specific user.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id != 19.
```

I can not do something like

`SELECT FROM Post WHERE user.id != 19`

because I don't have links between the classes, I have edges.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create class User extends V
create class Post extends V

create class Posted extends E

create vertex User set name = 'user1'     
create vertex User set name = 'user2'     

create vertex Post set name = 'post0'
create vertex Post set name = 'post1'
create vertex Post set name = 'post2'

create edge Posted from (select from Post where name = 'post0') to (select from User where name = 'user1')
create edge Posted from (select from Post where name = 'post1') to (select from User where name = 'user1')
create edge Posted from (select from Post where name = 'post2') to (select from User where name = 'user2')
```

If you have something similar to the above, and e.g., you want to know all posts not related with **user1** (that would be **post2**). Let's say the the Record ID of **user1** is **#12:0**.

You can:

```
select from Post where  #12:0 not in out('Posted')
// or
select expand(in('Posted')) from (select from User where @rid not in [#12:0])
```

The output:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**

You can also use the name of the user instead of its **@rid**:

```
select * from Post where $record_id.rid[0] not in out('Posted')
let $record_id = ( select @rid from User where name = 'user1' )
```

But note that the **let** clause is executed once for every **Post** (in this case, 3 times). This means that it won't be efficient when you have a lot of posts.

Comment: In the first example: How can I do the same, but instead of having the @rid, I have the name of the user to check?